# Sencha Touch - Undefined mixin 'experimental' on compass compile

Tags: ruby, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, compass

When I try to compile my sass code with `compass compile` I get the following error :

`error app.scss (Line 42 of /MyProject/touch/resources/themes/stylesheets/sencha-touch/base/src/_ProgressIndicator.scss: Undefined mixin 'experimental'.)`

My sass code is pretty normal, I have :

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

/* Rest of my css below */
```

I'm using :
`Sencha Touch 2.4` `Compass 1.0.1 (Polaris)` `ruby 2.2.0dev` `Mac OSX Yosemite`

Comment: I see the same issue too using Sencha Touch 2.3.1, Ruby 1.9.3, Compass 1.0.1 on windows. Has anyone seen the same issue. Is it related the latest compass version?

Comment: A rough workaround until we find a solution is to use `sencha app watch` on you app's root folder

Answer (score 4):

Adding `@import "compass/css3/shared";` to the project's `app.scss` resolves the error.  This import needs to be added before the sencha imports.

For subsequent errors I also had to add:

```
@import "compass/css3/box";
$experimental-support-for-pie:false;
```

Versions:
Sencha Touch: 2.4.1, Compass 1.0.1, Sass 3.4.9, Ruby 1.9.3

References:
http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/03/25/compass-extensions/,
http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box/,

Complete import to resolve the error:

```
@import "compass/css3/shared";
@import "compass/css3/box";
$experimental-support-for-pie: false;
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

<-- The rest of your sass -->
```